# Populating UITableViewCell with labels

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Okay so here's the issue...

I have a UITableView that has 3 sections and each section has a different amount of cells.
How would I insert an array(s) of labels that would go in the appropriate section and table..?

I can't figure this one out.

Solved:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }



    NSString *labelText;

    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            labelText = [_section1 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
        case 1:
            labelText = [_section2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
        case 2:
            labelText = [_section3 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            break;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = labelText;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/SimpleDrillDown.zip

Comment: Do u know basics of UITableView?

Comment: I can add labels to the cells, that's not really a problem. I'm just having difficulty adding them to specific sections using an NSDictionary.

Comment: can u clearly explain your problem i assume that your are not able to set proper text to label for particular section?@JulioLopez

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out it works now. I appreciate you looking at my question, though.